# how to make my AlarmManager work on all phones && How do I get permission to schedule my alarms without ever deleting them

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, scheduler

I tried a lot of codes and examples but I didn't find a solution to make my alarms work on all phones because on some phones when the app is destroyed the alarms are completely destroyed, some when I open the app again all the existing alarms start over
Is it true that my app should be in the whitelist? What is the solution?
However, there are apps on the Play Store that work well

```
  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void setAlarm() {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Alarm set Seccussfely",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Alarms are cleared when the device is rebooted, but not when an app is killed. You can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see (a lot of) informations about the registered alarms

Comment: In my phone it delete alarms it when it kills the app
How can I use adb shell dumpsys alarm

Comment: [adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) is a command line tool, part of the Android SDK, in the `platform-tools` directory.  Executing `adb` (or `adb.exe`) with the command `shell dumpsys alarm` dumps a list of known alarms. You can for example check before and after killing the application to see if your alarm is really removed, which would be strange

Comment: I will research this topic , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of AlarmManager, need to use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager). AlarmManager is old mechanizm for Android version till 6.0

Comment: How can I give the WorkManager a Exact time to work?